# How to Query dictionary based on a criteria in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I just started to play with python and flask :)

I've the below flask application that contains the dictionary, I am trying to query from the array based in a condition. for example: if the name matches john, display his displayName.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, send_from_directory
from flask import request
import subprocess
import json
import shlex
import socket
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

actors = {
  "actorname":[
  {
    "displayName": "john wick",
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "displayName": "george clooney",
    "name": "george"
  },
  {
    "displayName": "brad pitt",
    "name": "brad"
  }
  ]
 }


@app.route('/actors')
def theactors():

     return render_template('actors.html', actors=actors)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

in my actors.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title> Holywood actors </title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> the display name for the actor {{actors.actorname[0].name}} is  {{actors.actorname[0].displayName}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

so instead of specifying position 0 "actors.actorname[0].displayName" I would like to add a criteria to search the array for all name=john and display the displayName.

Answer (score 0):

Using the filter function of Python, you can achieve the desired effect. As an example, see the below code:

```
list(filter(lambda x:x['name']=='john',actors["actorname"]))
```

Comment: sorry but am new to python, where do I add that line ? isn't that possible in the html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple. Modify your app.py as:

```
    @app.route('/actors')
    def theactors():
        data = list(filter(lambda                                         
        x:x['name']=='john',actors["actorname"]))
        return render_template('actors.html', actors=data)
```

Then, your template file should be like:

```
    {{ actors }}
```

Comment: this worked but it gave me full output

```
[{'displayName': 'John wick', 'name': 'john'}]
```

the goal is to return the value only for the displayName == john. I also tried in the html to display {{actors.displayName}} but that returned nothing

Comment: <body>

{{ actors[0].displayName }}



</body>

Comment: actors is a list, so you have to index it to get the first element at 0 and then get the property displayName